# .NET Core Library not reading config file

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config, configurationmanager

I have Windows 10 computer. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I created a solution **MySolution**.

Inside the solution, first I created a *.NET Core Library project* named **MyLibrary**. Via Nuget Package Manager, I added `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` (5.0.0 version) and `System.Data.SqlClient` (4.8.2 version) packages to it.

I add an `Application Configuration File` named **App.Config** to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=10;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In this project I created a static class named **DatabaseInformation**. Inside that class I created a static constructor which is reading the configuration file:

```
static DatabaseInformation()
{
   ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];
}
```

Inside the solution, I then created a *.NET Core Console App project* named **MyConsoleApp** to test out the **MyLibrary** project. I added **MyLibrary** project's reference to it. Then write code to trigger the static constructor of `DatabaseInformation` class. Run in debug mode and find out it is not reading the config file, and the **settings** variable is null.

What could be the reason and how can I fix it? I can see the config file as **MyLibrary.dll.config** in **\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1** folder so it should have been read.

Comment: @KenTsu It does. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the App.Config file to the main solution and not in the class library project just like @KenTsu posted the comment to another stack question that says the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core the configuration system is very flexible, and the connection string could be stored in `appsettings.json`, an environment variable, the user secret store, or another configuration source. See the Configuration section of the ASP.NET Core documentation for more details.

For instance, you can use the Secret Manager tool to store your database password and then, in scaffolding,
use a connection string that simply consists of `Name=<database-alias>.`

```
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings.YourDatabaseAlias "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase"
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings.YourDatabaseAlias Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Or the following example shows the connection string stored in `appsettings.json.`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

Then the context is typically configured in `Startup.cs` with the connection string being read from configuration. Note the `GetConnectionString()` method looks for a configuration value whose key is `ConnectionStrings:<connection string name>.` You need to import the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace to use this extension method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```